# Unexpected Disk Capacity issue using Elasticsearch cluster on EKS with a 8Exabytes EFS disk

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I have configured an elasticsearch cluster in my kubernetes cluster (EKS), the elasticsearch cluster has 3 nodes and I have set up a 8E disk for the nodes to store the data. (thinking that I wont have any space issues for a while...)

```
[root@es-cluster-0 elasticsearch]# curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host         ip           node
    36       66.7gb   966.1gb   8191.9pb   8191.9pb            0 10.65.32.184 10.65.32.184 es-cluster-0
    33       82.6gb   966.1gb   8191.9pb   8191.9pb            0 10.65.32.202 10.65.32.202 es-cluster-2
    37         76gb   966.1gb   8191.9pb   8191.9pb            0 10.65.32.178 10.65.32.178 es-cluster-1
    14                                                                                     UNASSIGNED
```

The cluster current health is:

```
[root@es-cluster-0 elasticsearch]# curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "k8s-logs",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 56,
  "active_shards" : 106,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 14,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 88.33333333333333
}
```

I can see that I have 14 `"unassigned_shards"` which matches perfectly with the last line of the `/_cat/allocation` above

When I'm start figuring out what is happening I found this:

```
[root@es-cluster-0 elasticsearch]# curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty
{
  "index" : "logstash-2022.01.22",
  "shard" : 0,
  "primary" : false,
  "current_state" : "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
    "at" : "2022-01-22T00:00:11.254Z",
    "failed_allocation_attempts" : 5,
    "details" : "failed shard on node [bf_GjmcUQGuCTk-_voh4Xw]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[logstash-2022.01.22][0]: Recovery failed from {es-cluster-0}{hYJ4ifx7R7yWJq6VFP3Drw}{jjAAtdcmQXeVpJXxj4DYcA}{10.65.32.184}{10.65.32.184:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=15878057984, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true} into {es-cluster-1}{bf_GjmcUQGuCTk-_voh4Xw}{QNp4DD51TQa716D4TjMFPg}{10.65.32.178}{10.65.32.178:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=15878057984, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[es-cluster-0][10.65.32.184:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[es-cluster-1][10.65.32.178:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/clean_files]]; nested: UncategorizedExecutionException[Failed execution]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[execution_exception: java.io.IOException: Disk quota exceeded]; nested: IOException[Disk quota exceeded]; ",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
  },
  "can_allocate" : "no",
  "allocate_explanation" : "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
  "node_allocation_decisions" : [
    {
      "node_id" : "7WHft5LVTYCEWvwKM64A-w",
      "node_name" : "es-cluster-2",
      "transport_address" : "10.65.32.202:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "15878057984",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "true"
      },         
--- TRUNCATED ---
```

I don't know why it's saying `Disk quota exceeded` if the elasticsearch cluster is reporting correctly the capacity that it has available `/_cat/allocation` is there any additional configuration that I need to setup in order to tell elasticsearch that we have enough space to work with ?

Answer (score 0):

See here for [EFS limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting-efs-fileop-errors.html#diskquotaerror) that can cause disk quota error which is not necessary disk size related. Generally EFS does not support a sizeable ES stack, example elasticsearch expects 64K file descriptors per data node instance but EFS only support 32K at the moment. If you look into your elasticsearch logs there could be clue about which limitation has breached.